# How to align multiple text lines in one td

Tags: html, alignment, html-table

I need to have a few elements in a TD, and this td size is at most %50 of the table, and each line should be aligned to the left, but largest text should be "touching" the right side of the table.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="line-height: 20px; width: 49%;">
            <span style=" color: #FF00FF !important; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">Text First Cell
            </span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; text-align: right;">
            <span name="span1" style="float: left; width: 100%;">
            <span style="font-family: Arial !important; color: #FF00FF ; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">Text1 Second Cell Larger Text </span> 
            </span>
            <span name="span2" style="width: 100%; float: left;">
                <span style="font-family: Arial ; color: #FF00FF ; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;"> Text2 Second Cell
                </span>
            </span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I can almost do that, but I'm not being able to align to the left the text "Text1 Second Cell Larger Text" and "Text2 Second Cell".

Any ideas? 
Also, if there's a better way to do that, I'd love to know!

Comment: Hi, i don't really get your question. Do you wish to align  "Text1 Second Cell Larger Text" and "Text2 Second Cell" to the left of the table cell or do you wish to align" largest text should be "touching" the right side of the table"

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.. What I meant was align "Text1 Second Cell Larger Text" and "Text2 Second Cell" on the left. But also having  "Text1 Second Cell Larger Text" "touching" the right side of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just learned how to do it:

```
.myDiv {
    float: right;
}
.span1{
    display: block;
}


<div class="myDiv">
<span name="span1" class="span1" >
<span style="font-family: Arial !important; color: #FF00FF ; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">Text1 Second Cell Larger Text </span> 
</span>
<span name="span2" class="span2">
<span style="font-family: Arial ; color: #FF00FF ; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;"> Text2 Second Cell</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

i'm guessing you are having problems aligning texts because there are in the same cell. What i would suggest is to create multiple cells within the table so that it will be easier.

### Example:

```
<table border=0 width=546 style='table-layout:fixed'>
    <col width=67>
    <col width=75>
    <col width=41>

       <tr>

            <td width="147" rowspan="2"><span style="line-height: 20px; width: 49%;"> 
            <span style=" color: #FF00FF !important; font-size: 12pt; font-weight:bold;">
            Text First Cell </span> </span></td>

           <td width="389"><div align="right">
           <span style="font-family: Arial !important; color: #FF00FF ; 
           font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold;">
           Text1 Second Cell Larger Text </span></div></td>
       </tr>

       <tr>

          <td><span style="font-family: Arial ; color: #FF00FF ;
          font-size: 12pt; font-weight:  bold;">
          Text2 Second Cell </span></td>

      </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This actually won't really help me because, for other reasons, I'll need "Text1 Second Cell Larger Text" and "Text2 Second Cell" to be in the same cell. Maybe I could put them in another table, but I don't think this is the best solution...